# InvalidCastException being thrown when debugging webpage with database entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[Screenshot of error being thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mllAK.png)
I'm trying to figure out how to use the Entity Data Model because now that I am working in a team environment there is a separation of developers and db developers, so I am trying to get a quick understanding of how the an Entity Data Model is used. I have always created my own databases and stored procedures, etc... so having to use an Entity Model, is kind of confusing to me.

I'm using a Beginning ASP.NET 4.5 Databases book and I did what it said to do and when I go to debug the page it keeps throwing an error as shown in the added screenshot.

Here is the code in the code behind..

```
using (var db = new DGITestDBEntities())
        {
            this.MyRepeater.DataSource = db.Products.ToList();
            this.MyRepeater.DataBind();
        }
```

and the markup is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication13.DGITestDBEntities">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <label>
                    Name: <%# Item.Products %> 
                </label>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item type of the repeater is defined as `DGITestDBEntities`, which is a `DbContext`. It should be of the type that is bound to each item in the Repeater, which is `Product`...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication13.DGITestDBEntities">
```

Should be

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication13.Product">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **Repeater** implementation is different from me.

If you want to present product name from the field **`Products.name`**, Then I would code like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
           <label>
               Name: <%# Eval("name") %> 
           </label>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For your code behide to set Repeater DataSource, I think it should works fine.